# Flutter: block ListView scroll on specific widget

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-listview

My window contains some scrollable content with widgets. One widget in window is signature pad. User is able to scroll page content by swipe on any widget inside my window. I want to prevent that when user hold his thumb on signature pad widget, because scrolling causes user is not able to hand sign.

So, scroll inside ListView should work as usual, but it should be blocked when swipe is on one specific widget (signature pad). How to do that?

Comment: What is your target device

Comment: Do you mean platform? Device is Android